Video Gamma and Luminance
How can I calculate the luminance level of a given IRE level for Power Gamma.
Example:
Gamma = 2.4
Peak Luminance = 100
Black Level = 0.05
How would I calculate IRE15's luminance for example?
Can this be done easily in Excel?

What have you tried to do so far?
